# jQuery multiple selectors, get which selector triggered event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When handling events with multiple selectors, such as:

```
$('.item a, .another-item a').click(function(e) {

});
```

Is it possible to determine which parent selector triggered the event? Was it `.item` or `.another-item` ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are altering behavior based on the selector that matched the element, perhaps that's an indicator that you should be assigning separate handlers. This eliminates having to test the element every time an event occurs. If there's some common code, put it in a function and invoke it from both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a selector can be just about anything, you'd have to check for specific, such as:

```
if($(this).is('.item a')){
  //your code here
} else if ($(this).is('.another-item a')){
  //more here
}
```

Comment: `this` is `a` tag not the `.item` or `.another-item`

Comment: The selector is the anchor tag, not the `.item` or `.another-item` element

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery `is`.

```
if($(this).is('.item a')){
      // code
   }
   else if($(this).is('.another-item a')){//remove 'if ' in case there are only two selector separated by commas.
        //code..

   }
```

Comment: Why the `else if`? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: @user1689607 just in case OP want to add more selector separated by commas.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(this).closest('.item').length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check:

```
var isItem = $( this ).parents( '.item:first' ).length > 0,
    isAnotherItem = $( this ).parents( '.another-item:first' ).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.item` and `.another-item` belongs to 2 different nodes.. then you can try like below,

```
$('.item a, .another-item a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.item').length) {  //if it is '.item'

    } else {

    }
});
```