# Events with multiple selectors - how to get triggering selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When handling a jQuery event with multiple selectors, can I get the value of the selector triggered the event?

I'm aware of [jQuery multiple selectors, get which selector triggered event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941806/jquery-multiple-selectors-get-which-selector-triggered-event) and similar questions, but none of them seem to contain an answer to the fundamental question.

Suppose I have 3 buttons:

```
<button class='red stop danger'>red</button>
<button class='amber floor-it caution'>amber</button>
<button class='green go safe'>green</button>
```

With the accompanying Javascript code:

```
var clickCounts = {
    red: 0,
    green: 0
};

// we only want to count red and green clicks
$('.red, .green').click(function() {
    // can't use clickCounts[$(this).attr('class')] 
    // because there are multiple class values present
    clickCounts[??selector??] += 1;
});
```

If the only way to achieve this is by making a bunch of calls to `is()` or `hasClass()`, or write per-button handlers etc. then so be it, but I have yet to see a definitive answer.

Comment: call-back function of [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) supports a parameter ([`Event ev`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)). So you can use `ev.target` to pinpoint the element.

Answer (score 1):

Why not apply an ID to the button, and use that as your selector, instead of the class?

```
<button class='red stop danger' id="red">red</button>
<button class='green go safe' id="green">green</button>
```

Then:

`$('#red, #green').click(function() {
    clickCounts[$(this).attr('id')] += 1;
});`

Answer (score 1):

if you want **per button counts**,
i would personally stash it on a data attribute:

```
$('.red, .green').click(function() {
    lastCount = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;
    $(this).data('clicks', lastCount +1);
});
```

if you want **global red/green counts**,
i would do two separate handlers:

```
var clickCounts = {
    red: 0,
    green: 0
};

$('.red').click(function() {
    clickCounts.red += 1;
});

$('.green').click(function() {
    clickCounts.green += 1;
});
```

If you **are just curious**,
sorry I don't have an actual answer as to how to get the triggering selector for a jquery event; I suggest [posting an issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Element.matches()` and (for older browsers) `Element. matchesSelector`. For example:

```
$('.red, .green').click(function (e) {
    var sel;
    if ( e.target.matches && e.target.matches('.red') ||
         e.target. matchesSelector && e.target. matchesSelector('.red')) {
        sel = 'red';
    } else {
        sel = 'green';
    }
    clickCounts[sel] += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3z3bfp4/1/

```
<button name='red' class='red stop danger'>red</button>
<button class='amber floor-it caution'>amber</button>
<button name='green' class='green go safe'>green</button>

$('.red, .green').click(function(e) {
clickCounts[e.target.name] += 1;
alert('RED '+clickCounts.red);
alert('GREEN '+clickCounts.green)
});
```